# FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException when trying to do phone authentication using firebase. (ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting the following exception when I try to authenticate a user using a tester phone number (by firebase).

I am getting the following warning when I try to send OTP.

```
 W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@1d54205
```

I am getting the following exception when I try to verify credentials (verify the otp)

```
 com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException: This user's credential isn't valid for this project. This can happen if the user's token has been tampered with, or if the user isn't for the project associated with this API key.
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdw.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@18.1.0:6)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzez.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@18.1.0:21)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzes.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@18.1.0:35)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeu.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@18.1.0:74)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzec.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@18.1.0:18)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zza.onTransact(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@18.1.0:13)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:704)
```

I am getting the following error code for this exception: `ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN`.

The issue occurs only in the device **Redmi Y2**. in other devices, it is working fine. I tried to search for the solution. but i could not get any proper solution. can anyone please help me how to solve this?

Comment: Have you gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51764664/not-able-to-signin-with-google-and-facebook-after-deleting-data-from-firebase)?

Comment: yes i tried this solution. but its not working

Comment: this happens in oneplus 3t also